# Copy a value of an element into another element

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to find out how I can get the value of `<element1>value</element1>` into `<element16>value</element16>` in the same XML.

`<element16>` has not a fixed position, but if it exist it needs to be filled with the value of `<element1>`.

I have to do it with PowerShell. Who can give me a hand?

This is what I have:

```bsh
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir |
          Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 1
$latest.Fullname

$attachment = $latest.Fullname

$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load($latest.Fullname)

$xml.SelectSingleNode('/order/sf_st_mail').InnerText =
$xml.SelectSingleNode('/order/sf_re_mail').InnerText

$xml.Save($latest.Fullname)
```

This results in

> Exception setting "#text": "The property '#text' cannot be found on this object"

Snipplet XML:

```xml
<order>
  <sf_re_mail>abc@abc.com</sf_re_mail>

  <element x, y ,z> </element x, y ,z>
  <sf_st_mail></sf_st_mail>
</order>
```

should become:

```xml
<order>
  <sf_re_mail>abc@abc.com</sf_re_mail>

  <element x, y ,z> </element x, y ,z>
  <sf_st_mail>abc@abc.com</sf_st_mail>
</order>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the XML:

```
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load($latest)
```

Use XPath selectors in case the elements could be anywhere in the node tree:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode('//sf_st_mail').InnerText =
     $xml.SelectSingleNode('//sf_re_mail').InnerText
```

Or access them directly if you know the tree structure:

```
$xml.order.sf_st_mail = $xml.order.sf_re_mail # for simple text values
```

To replace a complex node with nested sub-nodes:

```
$xml.someNode.parentNode.ReplaceChild($xml.anotherNode.Clone(), $xml.someNode)
```

Then save:

```
$xml.Save($latest)
```

Comment: this results in "Exception setting "#text": "The property '#text' cannot be found on this object
. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At D:\test.ps1:16 char:1
+ $xml.SelectSingleNode('//sf_st_mail/.').'#text' =
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: tnx a lot, but unfortunally it returns The property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the proper
ty exists and can be set.. I'll check tomorrow after sleep.

Comment: you latest explaination did it.. tnx a lot.